# can't access my NavigationDrawer child views until a certain period

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I spent half an hour banging my head on this problem.. I couldn't access the child views of my navigation drawer this way :

```
TextView nameTv = (TextView) mNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_header_name);
nameTv.setText("bloblo");
```

This causes a null pointer exception (nameTv is null)

but if I put that in a short postDelayed (wanted to wait a bit for things to settle down) : it works fine !

```
        android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                menuInit();
            }
        },100);
```

Could somebody explain me why ? and how to have something more reliable than 100ms ?

Thanks,

Comment: Where are you accessing them from in the activity/fragment lifecycle?

Comment: I had the same problem and added a delay as well to get it to work. In other applications using earlier build it worked perfectly fine. I am not saying that is the problem but it may be an error with the library.

Comment: I'm trying to access it at the bottom of my activity's onCreate

Comment: There is no way to know when the drawer is ready ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
mNavigationView.post(new Runnable(){ @Override public void run() {and your code}}
```